# Faster/Better way to initialize object properties

Tags: c#, variables

Is there a way of doing this

```
Planets Mercury = new Planets();
Mercury.PlanetName = "Mercury";
Mercury.DistanceFromSun = 58000000;
Mercury.Mass = 33;
Mercury.EarthDaysForOrbit = 88;
Mercury.NumberOfMoons = 0;
```

but more efficiently / quicker /better?

Comment: Please explain _why_ this not enough efficient / quick / good? I would suggest to ask this on [CodeReview.SE] but I think this wouldn't fit there either.

Comment: What is this "more efficiently/quicker/better" you refer to? Does it mean "faster"? No, there is no such improvement. 

Does it mean "cleaner"? There might be something you can do which is called Object initializer as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
var Mercury = new Planets() 
{
    PlanetName = "Mercury",
    DistanceFromSun = 58000000,
    Mass = 33,
    EarthDaysForOrbit = 88,
    NumberOfMoons = 0
}
```

This code is shorter but it will be little bit slower because actually compiler will create temp variable and initialize it first and then assign this value to your actual variable.

Comment: How it be `more efficiently / quicker /better?` That too a part of the question

Comment: If you put some code that you think/know more efficiently / quicker / faster, please explain at least _why_ and/or show some test results that can verify your assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) like this:

```
Planets Mercury = new Planets
{
    PlanetName = "Mercury",
    DistanceFromSun = 58000000,
    Mass = 33,
    EarthDaysForOrbit = 88,
    NumberOfMoons = 0
};
```

The benefit of using a object initializer would first off be that a object would not get partially initialized. More than that this is just syntactic sugar, you save time not having to write the instance name for every property you want to add.

Comment: Error object must be this formet Planets Mercury = new Planets()

Comment: How it be `more efficiently / quicker /better?`

Comment: @KuttyRajeshValangai That's the beauty of it when using object initializer you dont need to use the paranthesis! :)

Comment: If you put some code that you think/know more efficiently / quicker / faster, please explain at least _why_ and/or show some test results that can verify your assumption.

Comment: @SonerGönul Well that depends on if the question is for faster performance. But how I understand it he is looking for a way to type this faster.